# Export two related layers to KML with multigeometry using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, kml, export, multi-geometry

From QGIS, I would like to create a KML file, for GoogleEarth, which contains multigeometry in that KML file.

By example: consider two layers in QGIS -- the first layer contains polygons, and the second layer contain points.   There is a one-to-one relation between the two layers; for each polygon there is one point which is centered on the polygon.

a)The polygon layer has information about the polygon (color, etc...), and unique AreaID, for each.

b) The point layer has symbol information, a unique AreaID, and other attributes.

In Google Earth, I want the KML for a point/polygon pair to be within a MultiGeometryTag.  Ultimately, the attributes will popup in a balloon.

How to merge/combine and then export the two QGIS layers so that they end up in a KML file with MultiGeometry?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, QGIS can't save out different geometry types (point & polygon) within the same MultiGeometry in a KML.  I think it might export MultiGeometries if you have multipart polygons in a layer, but combining geometry types is harder. In fact, I don't think there's a way to combine points & polygons in QGIS within the same layer, is there? For sure the Shapefile format only allows one geometry type (point, line or polygon) in a single shapefile.

You'll probably need to find some tool to process and combine your Point and Polygon KML files after exporting them separately from QGIS.